# Regular expression to match non-integer values in a string

Tags: regex

I want to match the following rules:

- One dash is allowed at the start of a number.
- Only values between 0 and 9 should be allowed.

I currently have the following regex pattern, I'm matching the inverse so that I can thrown an exception upon finding a match that doesn't follow the rules:

[^-0-9]

The downside to this pattern is that it works for all cases except a hyphen in the middle of the String will still pass. For example:

"-2304923" is allowed correctly but "9234-342" is also allowed and shouldn't be.

Please let me know what I can do to specify the first character as [^-0-9] and the rest as [^0-9]. Thanks!

Comment: Your pattern `[^-0-9]` is not matching what you say. This is a negated character class, that matches everything, but digits and the dash.

Comment: Is `9234` or `-342` part of what you want to capture? Or are you wanting to reject `9234-342` entirely?

Comment: The prolem is underspecified. What delineates a "non-integer" and an "integer"? Spaces? Punctuation? The title says you are looking for these values "in" a string. Does the entire string have to be an integer? Or just part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will work for you:

```
^-?\d+$
```

Explanation: start the string `^`, then `-` but optional (`?`), the digit `\d` repeated few times (`+`), and string must finish here `$`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
(?:^|\s)(-?\d+)(?:["'\s]|$)

 ^^^^^                        non capturing group for start of line or space
         ^^^^^                capture number
                 ^^^^^^^^^    non capturing group for end of line, space or quote
```

[See it work](http://regexr.com?33ngh)

This will capture all strings of numbers in a line with an optional hyphen in front.

```
-2304923"  "9234-342"   1234 -1234 
++++++++                                   captured
            ^^^^^^^^                       NOT captured
                        ++++               captured
                             +++++         captured
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how your pattern - `[^-0-9]` is matching those strings you are talking about. That pattern is just the opposite of what you want. You have simply negated the character class by using `caret(^)` at the beginning. So, this pattern would match anything except the `hyphen` and the `digits`.

Anyways, for your requirement, first you need to match one `hyphen` at the beginning. So, just keep it outside the character class. And then to match any number of digits later on, you can use `[0-9]+` or `\d+`.

So, your pattern to match the required format should be:

```
-[0-9]+  // or -\d+
```

The above regex is used to find the pattern in some large string. If you want the entire string to match this pattern, then you can add anchors at the ends of the regex: -

```
^-[0-9]+$
```

Comment: I don't think I explained it perfectly yet, I'm matching the inverse of the pattern because I'm throwing an exception upon match. However, the problem I'm encountering is that the hyphen isn't required. The string "32049234" should also pass (no hyphen necessary).

Comment: If hyphen is not required then just use - `-?[0-9]+`. This will make `-` optional. And rather than checking for inverse of this pattern, you should match this pattern and see if it returns true or false.

Comment: Perfect! I added a ^ to the start and a $ to the end to verify that the full String matches the pattern exactly and it should cover all cases. Final pattern: ^-?[0-9]+$

Comment: @sailboatlie. Ok. Try it if it works. Frankly I didn't get exactly what you wanted to do. But still if it works with the given regex, then it's fine/

Comment: @sailboatlie: you ended up with what was offered in my answer

Answer (score 0):

For a regular expression like this, it's sometimes helpful to think of it in terms of two cases.

- Is the first character messed up somehow?
- If not, are any of the other characters messed up somehow?
- Combine these with `|`

```
 (^[^-0-9]|^.+?[^0-9])
```

[image]

Comment: @dawg see regexper.com, it's very helpful!